# Jest Test - Spy on named module constructor

Tags: javascript, ajax, rxjs

I am writing unit test using jest, enzyme, react and rxjs. I mocked rxjs/ajax like this.

```
import { ajax } from 'rxjs/ajax';
jest.mock('rxjs/ajax', () => {
    return {
        ajax: jest.fn().mockImplementation((args) => {
            return {
                subscribe: jest.fn().mockImplementation(args => {
                    return {
                        unsubscribe: jest.fn(),
                    }
                })
            }
        })
    }
})
```

In my componentDidMount() I added subscription from rxjs/ajax call.

```
    componentDidMount() {

        this.mySubscription = ajax({
            url: `/api/mycontroller/myAction/`,
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                Authorization: `Bearer ${Auth.getToken()}`,
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
        }).subscribe({
            next: (response) => {
                MyService.setData(response.response);
            },
            error: console.log,
        });
    }
```

My question is how to write assertion to make sure the url params in ajax module is expected.

```
        it("should call ajax with url when it's mounted", () => {
            let spyOn = jest.spyOn(ajax, 'constructor');
            let wrapper = shallow(<MyComponent {...defaultProps} />);
            expect(spyOn).toHaveBeenCalledWith({ url:"/api/mycontroller/myAction/"})
        })
```

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

This is fixed by calling
`let spyOn = jest.spyOn(ajax.prototype, 'constructor');`